# Passing a changing value from 1 webcomponent into another

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have 2 webcomponents, which have the same linked value

```
<my-input value="{{data}}"></my-input>
<my-output value="{{data}}"></my-output
```

So that way, when i change a paper input in `my-input` it will change the attribute *value* in `my-output` accordingly.

The issue is that nothing ends up displaying, even on the basecase of output being:

```
<div>Data: {{value}}</div>
```

so it seems that the variable isnt linked to both components.

the *data* variable is defined as:

```
@property String data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the definition in the components for *value* you need to have:

```
@Property(notify:true)
String value;
```

so that way it propagates up.   It seems that without this, it just stops the propagation.  This will then push the changed value up a level to the parent `data` variable.

As a follow on:  It is only needing to notify if the variable itself is changed inside of the Web Component.  That is dependent entirely on your design.

Comment: Specifically, it is probably the `my-input` element only that needs to do this. If an element doesn't ever modify the variable itself then it likely doesn't need that (which is presumably the case for `my-output`).